# pma designer create relation popup doesnt work correctly

Tags: phpmyadmin

As i desribed the pma designer "create relation popup" doesnt work correctly. I see just a empty window. This appearce if you want to make a relation between a key and row without an index defined.

pma version is: 3.4.10.1deb1
firefox 16.0.2

In the config.inc... everything is turned on.